# Container cannot be started from bootlocal.sh

Tags: docker, boot2docker

Running Boot2Docker 1.5.0 under Windows. A container `gastrobase` exists and can be started manually with `docker start gastrobase`.

When I put this command into `/var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh`, upon startup I get

`Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.17/containers/gastrobase/start: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
time="2015-03-28T19:50:51Z" level="fatal" msg="Error: failed to start one or more containers"`

in `var/log/bootlocal.log`.

Running `./bootlocal.sh` manually starts Ok.

I have already tried the `sudo`-variant, which according to another thread in SO is the wrong choice with Boot2Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This proved to be a racing condition: With the following in `bootlocal.sh` startup works

`sleep 1
docker start gastrobase`

RomanSaveljev suggested

`docker run --restart=always --name gastrobase`

instead.